# Migrating Hyper-V VM's to CentOS 6

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, kvm-virtualization, centos6

I have tried to search this around in google, but I haven't actually found anyone migrating from Hyper-V (Windows) to CentOS 6, only the other way around. So, I was wondering if there are any pointers I could use for this?

Specifically, here is what I want to do:
I already have a running OS emulated with Hyper-V. I want to import that virtual machine to QEMU, at the very least, just reuse the drive (vhd). Is this possible, and if it is, how can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You just need to use a tool like [virt-v2v](http://libguestfs.org/virt-v2v/) to make the image conversion.

Additionally, if you google "convert hyper-v to rhel kvm" you'll find many tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

`virt-v2v` doesn't cover hyper-v. What you need is `virt-p2v` and treat the original hyper-v based VM as a physical machine.

EDIT early 2020 (since this post seems to be receiving downvotes from people who can't see the original post is from 2014): `virt-v2v` seems to be able to import vhdx files properly now. It still does not work with Hyper-V directly (as in hook up to a running Hyper-V and pull the specified VMs out of it) but it can import a disk that has been exported from Hyper-v in `vhdx` format, which makes things somewhat more usable than 6 years ago. It is still not full proper support, but it is better than it used to be.

Comment: I don't really care about downvotes, but if anyone decides to do that, I expect a comment with an explanation.

Comment: Yes I would like to know why someone downvoted this... it's 2018 and AFAIK virt-v2v still does not support Hyper-V, which is a shame. I'm considering a qemu-img convert with the VHD file from Hyper-V, but I'm unsure if this would end up with a working VM.

Comment: It probably will not, since the virtio drivers will not be injected into the image. Your best bet is virt-p2v or backup everything inside the source VM and restore into a target VM after setting up it's OS

Comment: So if the VHD disk can be bootable on other hypervisor, I can add the drivers and then use the qemu-img process?

Comment: If this is a Windows VM, you have certain Hyper-V specific disk controller drivers installed and enabled, so that the VM can use the virtual disk. KVM has different disk controllers. Effectively, what you get by booting up the image on a different hypervisor, is the same effect as if you took a hard drive from one machine and put it in a nother, with different hardware. It might work but chances are it will not.